# How to obtain quaternion from rotation matrix in Android?

Tags: android, android-sensors, quaternions

I'm trying to obtain the orientation of an android device, and I need it to be in a quaternion structure (`float[4]` basically).

What I have now is this:

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
    last_acc = (float[])event.values.clone();
}
else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
    last_mag = (float[])event.values.clone();
}
if (last_acc != null && last_mag != null){
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotation, inclination, last_acc, last_mag);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(rotation, orientation);
```

In "rotation", I have the 4x4 rotation matrix, and in orientation I have a float[3] vector where I have the azimuth, pitch and roll.

How can I get now the quaternion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't use Euler angles (roll, pitch, yaw), it pretty much [screws up the stability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578867/341970) of your app.

As for converting the rotation matrix to quaternion, Google says:

- [From an orthogonal matrix to a quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion)
- [Conversion Matrix to Quaternion](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm)

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I think this is what I need. Also, the google video that explains it is very clear. Thanx again :)

Comment: @Alex Glad to hear it. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind only being available to API Level 9 and higher, you can use `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`, which returns a unit quaternion anyway and saves you the work. If fed an array of length 3, the values will be the vector portion of the quaternion satisfying `sin(theta / 2) * u`, where `u` is a 3D unit vector. If the array is of length 4, the fourth value will be the scalar value of the unit quaternion, `cos(theta / 2)`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values