# How can I better my results when measuring the roll of a device in portrait mode?

Tags: java, android, rotation, hardware

I am trying to take the pitch and roll of a device when in portrait orientation.  [With the axes looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv5uN.png), it would be about the x and z axis respectively. Right now I'm using the SensorManager API to get the pitch, roll, and yaw of the device sitting flat, [as is default.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXMdO.jpg)

When I try and translate the rotational values from the flat device to the vertical orientation I experience what other SO users have called gimbal lock, which is a problem inherent in the way Euler angles work. Problem is I've tried implementing a rotational matrix, [as other users have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454948/android-pitch-and-roll-issue) to solve a similar problem, but even still I'm having the same gimbal lock problem. I've included my onSensorChanged method and hopefully someone out there could help find out what's going wrong.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {

    float degPitch = 0;
    float degRoll = 0;
    float degYaw = 0;
    float radPitch = 0;
    float radRoll = 0;
    float radYaw = 0;

    if (se.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        mAccelerometerResult = se.values;
        Log.d("onSensorChanged", "Accelerometer: " + mAccelerometerResult.length);
    }

    if (se.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        mMagneticFieldResult = se.values;
        Log.d("onSensorChanged", "Magnetic Field: " + mMagneticFieldResult.length);
    }

    if (mAccelerometerResult != null && mMagneticFieldResult != null) {
        float[] rotation = new float[9];
        float[] inclination = new float[9];

        boolean rotationMatrixCheck = mSensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotation, inclination, mAccelerometerResult, mMagneticFieldResult);

        if (rotationMatrixCheck) {

            float[] orientation = new float[3];
            mSensorManager.getOrientation(rotation, orientation);


            radYaw = orientation[0];      //Yaw = Z axis
            radPitch = orientation[1];      //Pitch = X axis
            radRoll = orientation[2];      //Roll = Y axis

            degYaw = round((float) Math.toDegrees(radYaw), 2);
            degPitch = round((float)Math.toDegrees(radPitch), 2);
            degRoll = round((float)Math.toDegrees(radRoll), 2);


            if ((counter % 10) == 0) {
                //mYawTextView.setText(degYaw + "°");
                mPitchTextView.setText(degPitch + "°");
                mRollTextView.setText(degRoll + "°");
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Further, I'm not even sure that I understand what rotational value I'm looking for if I can get good rotation about the portrait axes. If I want the roll of the device in portrait (about z axis from my original image), would that still be the roll of the device laying flat(about y from the flat axes image)?

Any insight that can be shared here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. Getting the rotational matrix in a 3x3 grid returns the rotational matrix in Euler's angles, as discussed in the original question. Getting the matrix in a 4x4 grid returns a Quaternion representation of the rotational matrix [(According to SO user Stochastically's answer found here).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17011172/5768647)

Further that rotational matrix coordinate system had to be remapped in order to be used in portrait mode. commented changes are shown bellow.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {

float degPitch = 0;
float degRoll = 0;
float degYaw = 0;
float radPitch = 0;
float radRoll = 0;
float radYaw = 0;

if (se.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    mAccelerometerResult = se.values;
    Log.d("onSensorChanged", "Accelerometer: " + mAccelerometerResult.length);
}

if (se.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
    mMagneticFieldResult = se.values;
    Log.d("onSensorChanged", "Magnetic Field: " + mMagneticFieldResult.length);
}

if (mAccelerometerResult != null && mMagneticFieldResult != null) {

//~~~This is where the 3x3 matrix has changed to a 4x4.
    float[] rotation = new float[16];
    float[] inclination = new float[16];

    boolean rotationMatrixCheck = mSensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotation, inclination, mAccelerometerResult, mMagneticFieldResult);

    if (rotationMatrixCheck) {

        float[] orientation = new float[3];

//~~~This is where the rotational matrix is remapped to be used in portrait mode.
        float[] remappedRotation = new float[16];
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotation, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, remappedRotation);

        mSensorManager.getOrientation(rotation, orientation);


        radYaw = orientation[0];      //Yaw = Z axis
        radPitch = orientation[1];      //Pitch = X axis
        radRoll = orientation[2];      //Roll = Y axis

        degYaw = round((float) Math.toDegrees(radYaw), 2);
        degPitch = round((float)Math.toDegrees(radPitch), 2);
        degRoll = round((float)Math.toDegrees(radRoll), 2);


        if ((counter % 10) == 0) {
            //mYawTextView.setText(degYaw + "°");
            mPitchTextView.setText(degPitch + "°");
            mRollTextView.setText(degRoll + "°");
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```