# How should I calculate 3 axis of "world coordinates" from device motion?

Tags: objective-c, ios, accelerometer, augmented-reality, gyroscope

I am having trouble converting the device motion data into world coordinates.

I have been looking into rotation/projection matrixes and quaternion but `CMAttitude` (`roll`, `pitch`, `yaw`) is where is have had most success using `gravity.y` & `gravity.z` to find the device orientation around the same axis as `pitch`.

The end result i am looking for is a augmented/virtual reality feel as the user looks for 2D game objects around a center point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use **Euler angles** (roll, pitch, yaw). It pretty much screws up the stability of your app, see here why: [Strange behavior with android orientation sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578867/341970).

I would use rotation matrices. These tell you how to go from device coordinates to world coordinates and the other way around. You might find these useful:

- [Theoretical intro](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9rLLz1XQKmaZTlQdV81QjNoZTA/view?usp=share_link&resourcekey=0-tMmw1tSCJzcthOHDaPqdyA)
- [Developer guide, see rotationMatrix](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Know any public source code taking this in use ? Wont mind fees.

Comment: The linked theoretical intro is really good and easy to understand. I do not think any source code would be easier to understand than that.

Comment: I have been looking into http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/pARk/Listings/pARk_ARView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011083-pARk_ARView_m-DontLinkElementID_5 but replacing the functions that converts the GPS coordinates into the projection matrix has been difficult.

Comment: GPS coordinates have nothing to do with the device attitude. You cannot convert GPS coordinates to rotation matrices.

Comment: I know, the Park app translates GPS coordinates into ECEF then into ENU then into an quaternion and feeds that to a projection Matrix. I have tried creating a quaternion with my game objects startpositions and feed that to the matrix but no luck so far.

Comment: @Lohardt Glad to see you find my answer helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Links broken, anyone know where it can be accessed?

Comment: @JCutting8 Thanks for the info, I have fixed that broken link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a tilt-based app and thought I'd share what I ended up finding. This code converts from a quaternion to Euler (Looks like XYX, or ZYZ) and Tait-Bryan angles (looks like XYZ, or ZYX), although I've only used the Tait-Bryan ones myself. After guessing-and-checking through the Tait-Bryan angles, I discovered ZXY worked perfectly for my purposes.

Here's the link: http://bediyap.com/programming/convert-quaternion-to-euler-rotations/

And here's the code:

```
///////////////////////////////
// Quaternion to Euler
///////////////////////////////
enum RotSeq{zyx, zyz, zxy, zxz, yxz, yxy, yzx, yzy, xyz, xyx, xzy,xzx};

void twoaxisrot(double r11, double r12, double r21, double r31, double r32, double res[]){
  res[0] = atan2( r11, r12 );
  res[1] = acos ( r21 );
  res[2] = atan2( r31, r32 );
}

void threeaxisrot(double r11, double r12, double r21, double r31, double r32, double res[]){
  res[0] = atan2( r31, r32 );
  res[1] = asin ( r21 );
  res[2] = atan2( r11, r12 );
}

void quaternion2Euler(const Quaternion& q, double res[], RotSeq rotSeq)
{
    switch(rotSeq){
    case zyx:
      threeaxisrot( 2*(q.x*q.y + q.w*q.z),
                     q.w*q.w + q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                    -2*(q.x*q.z - q.w*q.y),
                     2*(q.y*q.z + q.w*q.x),
                     q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y + q.z*q.z,
                     res);
      break;

    case zyz:
      twoaxisrot( 2*(q.y*q.z - q.w*q.x),
                   2*(q.x*q.z + q.w*q.y),
                   q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y + q.z*q.z,
                   2*(q.y*q.z + q.w*q.x),
                  -2*(q.x*q.z - q.w*q.y),
                  res);
      break;

    case zxy:
      threeaxisrot( -2*(q.x*q.y - q.w*q.z),
                      q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x + q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                      2*(q.y*q.z + q.w*q.x),
                     -2*(q.x*q.z - q.w*q.y),
                      q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y + q.z*q.z,
                      res);
      break;

    case zxz:
      twoaxisrot( 2*(q.x*q.z + q.w*q.y),
                  -2*(q.y*q.z - q.w*q.x),
                   q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y + q.z*q.z,
                   2*(q.x*q.z - q.w*q.y),
                   2*(q.y*q.z + q.w*q.x),
                   res);
      break;

    case yxz:
      threeaxisrot( 2*(q.x*q.z + q.w*q.y),
                     q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y + q.z*q.z,
                    -2*(q.y*q.z - q.w*q.x),
                     2*(q.x*q.y + q.w*q.z),
                     q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x + q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                     res);
      break;

    case yxy:
      twoaxisrot( 2*(q.x*q.y - q.w*q.z),
                   2*(q.y*q.z + q.w*q.x),
                   q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x + q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                   2*(q.x*q.y + q.w*q.z),
                  -2*(q.y*q.z - q.w*q.x),
                  res);
      break;

    case yzx:
      threeaxisrot( -2*(q.x*q.z - q.w*q.y),
                      q.w*q.w + q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                      2*(q.x*q.y + q.w*q.z),
                     -2*(q.y*q.z - q.w*q.x),
                      q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x + q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                      res);
      break;

    case yzy:
      twoaxisrot( 2*(q.y*q.z + q.w*q.x),
                  -2*(q.x*q.y - q.w*q.z),
                   q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x + q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                   2*(q.y*q.z - q.w*q.x),
                   2*(q.x*q.y + q.w*q.z),
                   res);
      break;

    case xyz:
      threeaxisrot( -2*(q.y*q.z - q.w*q.x),
                    q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y + q.z*q.z,
                    2*(q.x*q.z + q.w*q.y),
                   -2*(q.x*q.y - q.w*q.z),
                    q.w*q.w + q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                    res);
      break;

    case xyx:
      twoaxisrot( 2*(q.x*q.y + q.w*q.z),
                  -2*(q.x*q.z - q.w*q.y),
                   q.w*q.w + q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                   2*(q.x*q.y - q.w*q.z),
                   2*(q.x*q.z + q.w*q.y),
                   res);
      break;

    case xzy:
      threeaxisrot( 2*(q.y*q.z + q.w*q.x),
                     q.w*q.w - q.x*q.x + q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                    -2*(q.x*q.y - q.w*q.z),
                     2*(q.x*q.z + q.w*q.y),
                     q.w*q.w + q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                     res);
      break;

    case xzx:
      twoaxisrot( 2*(q.x*q.z - q.w*q.y),
                   2*(q.x*q.y + q.w*q.z),
                   q.w*q.w + q.x*q.x - q.y*q.y - q.z*q.z,
                   2*(q.x*q.z + q.w*q.y),
                  -2*(q.x*q.y - q.w*q.z),
                  res);
      break;
    default:
      std::cout << "Unknown rotation sequence" << std::endl;
      break;
   }
}
```