# Attitude calculation from mems gyroscope

Tags: gyroscope

I'm using MEMS gyroscope to calculate orientation of device(Yaw, Pitch and roll). I got following pdf which specifies about how to process raw data available from chip and calculate orientation. This doc tells about using quaternion to do calculations. Can anyone tell me about how to process the equation 14(build quaternion and multiply it with angular rate) on page 37 in this document.

http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/TECHNICAL_ARTICLE/DM00034730.pdf

Thank

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the [Direction Cosine Matrix IMU: Theory](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rLLz1XQKmaZTlQdV81QjNoZTA) manuscript, I have implemented sensor fusion for [Shimmer 2](http://www.shimmer-research.com/products-2/shimmer-revisions) devices based on it.

That manuscript is basically a tutorial, pretty straightforward and simple. It also uses rotation matrices instead of quaternions and rotation matrices are easier to understand.

Do not use yaw, pitch and roll, [Euler angles are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5577334/341970).

Well, good luck!