# getting angle using gyroscope in android

Tags: android, gyroscope

Can I calculate the angle from gyroscope with this code? I mean is the calculation of dT correct?

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
      /* Other sensor cases */
           case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE: 
            for (int j=0;j<3;j++) mGyro[j] = event.values[j];
            if(i==0)
                i=1;
            else
                i=2;
            if(i==1)
                start=System.nanoTime();
                else if(i==2) {
                    finish=System.nanoTime();
                 dT=( finish-start )/1000000000f;
                             i=0;
                }

            angle[0]=(float) ((angle[0]+mGyro[0]*dT)*180/3.1428f);
            angle[1]=(float) ((angle[1]+mGyro[0]*dT)*180/3.1428f);
            angle[2]=(float) ((angle[2]+mGyro[0]*dT)*180/3.1428f);

            break;
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to get the orientation. No, those formulas are not correct, this is not how you integrate the angular rates in 3D, that is a bit tricky actually.

If you want angles then just use [SensorManager.getOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) from the API. In other words, somebody has already written this code for you, there is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Do **not** use yaw, pitch and roll for arbitrary orientations, [Euler angles are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5577334/341970).

If your goal is to learn, you can find how the integration in 3D in [Direction Cosine Matrix IMU: Theory](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rLLz1XQKmaZTlQdV81QjNoZTA) manuscript. This manuscript is basically a tutorial, pretty straightforward and simple.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the [SensorEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) class gives a full example of how to use the gyroscope. You basically only have to copy and paste the code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18800083/448357) on how to get an orientation from the gyroscope.